# Interactive ( Real-time ) Particle Sytem on Android with Opengl ES 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'd like to make a smoke particle system where you can interact with the paritcles like they bounce of from an object or you can push them ect.
So far I managed to create one with the help of this paper:
[this](http://www.intpowertechcorp.com/GDC03.pdf)

My problem is that the fps drops drastically because of the huge amount of CPU calculation. My idea was that I pass the calculations to the GPU but I realised I have no idea how to get data back from the shader. Is there a way to get back data from the shader?

Or could someone point me to the right direction to create a particle system like this?

Comment: Are you sure its from the CPU calculation? I would bet that the slowdown is due to vm garbage collection popping hard.

Comment: I don't think so gc only gets called when I start the app after that nothing